# In Android Studio For Mac context Actions are not being displayed

Tags: flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea, flutter-layout, dart-analyzer

I have tried to enable the context actions in android studio but am not able to find any suggestions.

[when I press option + enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snKBz.png)

[Checked in settings > intentions > Dart analysis still no use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yYyC.png)

[Checked in settings > preferences > Keymap it is still option + enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsklK.png)

Please tell me how can I enable the suggestions for example

[For Example this menu is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6OkR.png)

Thank you

Comment: Try restarting dart analysis

Comment: I have restarted the dart analysis but still I am not able to view the action menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the help I have reinstalled dart plugin in android studio am now able to access the context action menu after enabling the setting below.

[This is the settings I have enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUm8v.jpg)

Comment: Always try to add the samples or the exact changes you've made in text format. For eg. the image your shared contains a lot of contents, to try to get the settings name and write it as a text to help more with the image

Answer (score 0):

For those who have enabled `Quick assists powered by Dart Analysis Server` and yet still does not work, please make sure that you have checked `Scope analysis to the current package` in Dart Analysis Server Settings.

[image: Screenshot]